TABLE_PER_CLASS and Independent identifier managment
Suppose I have an abstract parent class and two child classes that implement this parent class. If I want each child class to handle its identifiers independently, rather than having the parent class manage them, how can I achieve this? What I mean is that I want instances of Child Class 1 to have IDs starting from 1, and Child Class 2 to also have IDs starting from 1, so that it’s possible for Child Class 1 to have an ID of 1 and for Child Class 2 to also have an ID of 1.
Here some code i wrote but couldnt make it work:
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Parent {
}

@Entity
public class FirstChild extends Cuenta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
public class SecondChild extends Cuenta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;



Did you try @SequenceGenerator already? It allows you to specify the name of the sequence. That does mean you need separate sequences, but with only one sequence it's impossible to let both tables start at 1.
